# VMware vCenter Converter Standalone Error: Unable to obtain hardware information for the selected machine

Tags: windows-10, vmware, vmware-workstation, vcenter

I am running VMware Workstation 15.5.7 on Windows 10.  I create a new Windows 10 x64 VM, which starts up and runs with no issues.  I want to change this VM's hardware compatibility so that it can run on earlier versions of VMWare Workstation.  I launch VMware vCenter Converter Standalone 6.3.0, point it at the newly created - and powered off - Windows 10 VM and it reports

> Unable to obtain hardware information for the selected machine.

When I point vCenter Converter Standalone to other VMs on my system (mostly Windows 10 machines, but others as well), it works fine, being able to read the hardware information.  Why can't it read the hardware information for this newly created Windows 10 x64 machine?

I have tried running vCenter Converter Standalone as the Administrator.  This produces the same error described above.

Comment: According to the product documentation page, it should convert Windows 10 64-bit. Did you fully shut down the VM and exit (close) the VMware App? That is about all I can think of at this point.

Comment: @John Yes, fully shut down.